# How do I find the default properties to set on JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Looking at the jqm repository, they have a tool called https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/tools/config-props.html config-props.

However, downloading the repo, and running it on my local machine ends up with the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < file:///C:/Users/Ryan/Downloads/jquery-mobile-1.3-stable/jquery-mobile-1.3-stable/js/:1

From config-props.html

```
<script src="../external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/"></script>
```

The issue is that chrome is treating the /js/ directory as a html index page listing the contents of the folder, instead of including all the javascript files within into the page.

Is this a problem with chrome? Does the tool have errors? or is there some sort of preprocessing that needs to be performed first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view this page online on their documentation.

It isn't very well published, but some url tweaking / exploring after following a broken link led to this

http://jquerymobile.com/resources/#Tools

Broken link on page: http://jquerymobile.com/test/tools/log-page-events.html

Which looks similar to https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/e377564aa121d0439a21bc97f7854ee618c3f72d/tools/log-page-events.html

redirected to

http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/

Which looked suspiciously like a hosted version of the github repo.

changing to

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3-stable/tools/ resulted in an index page that led to

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3-stable/tools/config-props.html